# Sci4AutoHotkey crashes when using emojis

Tags: autohotkey, emoticons, scite

This Autohotkey script works when I write it in Notepad:

```
!Numpad1::Send 
!Numpad2::Send 
!Numpad3::Send 
!Numpad4::Send
```

But if I copy and paste it into SciTE4AutoHotkey, the application crashes.

Adjusting the `File > Encoding` options does not fix the problem.

Is there a way for SciTE4AutoHotkey to support Emojis?

**Stupid workaround:** *Put your emojis in another script (using Notepad), and promise yourself never to open that script in SciTE4AutoHotkey. Then call that script from inside your main script, which you can edit in SciTE4AutoHotkey. I told you it was stupid.*

Comment: Please post your answer on the answer box, not in the question.

Comment: Try to contact the author in the AHK forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send emojis and still use SciTE for your editor, find the extended Unicode mappings for the emoji you would like to use then use the respective codings for each symbol you want to send (instead of embedding the symbols themselves directly in your script).

For example, you can `send % chr(0x1F44D)` or `send {U+1F44D}`

Also, the website https://unicode-table.com/en/ will let you search using English descriptions of the icons you want to find, or icon sets.

In this case you may be interested in the codes for emoticons for example:

https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/emoticons/